# Using an aggregate function to filter the output

Tags: python

I have a function that returns a list of strings that are being compared to one another and a score for each observation. I am trying to filter the output to scores that are greater than or equal to 80. When I applied the .filter it returned a list of true or false when I wanted a list of strings with a score of 80 or more.

```
#Assign your list1
Test_addrs = my_list1
#Assign your List2 and build the nested loop
target_addr = my_list2
for addr in Test_addrs:
    for target in target_addr:
        distance = string_match(target, addr, ratio_calc = True)
        #write results to a txt file
        mylist.append(f'{target}, {addr}, {distance}')
```

Comment: I don’t understand what the code you’ve shown has to do with the text. There is no function, no score, and no filter.

Comment: So you have two lists: strings list and scores list?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The function is gigantic so for simplicity I left it out . I display the code in which I call in the function and append it to a list. I will edit the post though if it helps with the context.

Comment: @Austin That is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip()` with a list-comprehension:

```
strings_lst = ['a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g']
scores_lst = [21, 24, 90, 54, 109]

print([x for x, y in zip(strings_lst, scores_lst) if y >= 80])
# ['d', 'g']
```

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was working on and trying to figure out.

Comment: Next time give us input, expected output and right code applicable to what you are explaining. This avoids further queries in the comments.